# Container within a Container size

Tags: flutter-layout

I created a container within another container within it. The child container is supposed to be smaller than the parent but this is not working. I only see the border of the child container.

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.green),
        child: Container(
            height: 200,
            width: 200,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.red),
          child: Card(
            child: Text('fffff'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a `Stack` and a `Positioned` Widget for that like so:

```
Container(
          width: 200,
          height: 200,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.blue,
          ),
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Positioned(
                left: 20.0,
                top: 20.0,
                child: Container(
                  height: 100,
                  width: 100,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.green),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
```